# geometry question regarding the adjustable angle of a climbing wall and how to lower the overall height

Tags: geometry

I would greatly appreciate some help to work out how to reduce the overall vertical height of an adjustable climbing wall. The wall angle and height adjusts by changing where the frame that supports the wall attaches to the the vertical upright.
I need to get it below 2430 in vertical height. ( i also then need to convince my wife I should put it in the house and not the shed, but that's another problem)
I have tried to sketch it out and will try to attach the drawing.
[image: climbing wall sketch]